# String::toByteArray() does not compile in Kotlin [js]

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-interop

The following code does not compile in Kotlin Js:

```
"My String".toByteArray()
```

Any ideas why?

The error returned is:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.51:js (compile-js) @ client ---
[INFO] Kotlin version 1.1.51 (JRE 1.8.0_144-b01)
[INFO] Compiling Kotlin sources from [C:\myproject\src\main\kotlin]
[ERROR] C:\myproject\src\main\kotlin\mypackage\MyFile.kt: (15, 48) Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun Array<out Byte>.toByteArray(): ByteArray defined in kotlin.collections
public fun Collection<Byte>.toByteArray(): ByteArray defined in kotlin.collections
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
```

The same code compiles in the non-javascript Kotlin compilation:

```
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.51:compile (compile) @ client ---
[INFO] Kotlin version 1.1.51 (JRE 1.8.0_144-b01)
[INFO] Compiling Kotlin sources from [C:\myproject\src\main\kotlin, C:\myproject\src\main\java]
[INFO] Module name is client
[INFO]
```

Comment: `String.toByteArray()` is from `kotlin-stdlib`/`kotlin-text`. Have a included a reference on that? According to this page: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.toByteArray` function is not provided in the Kotlin/JS standard library.

[The documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html) of that function has a section about Platform and version requirements. `JVM` there means that it's only available on Kotlin/JVM.

Comment: Is there a reason why isn't it available on every platform?